# tcp client server p2p

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Where does the `connect()` system call need to be placed in the context of a tcp server in order to function as both a client and server system? I need to build a p2p client/server system. The template for the server process is: *create server_socket, bind, listen, loop(accept, fork, send/recv)* and the client template is: *create client_socket, connect*. Can i do this?

```
sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(sockfd, &saddr, sizeof(saddr));
listen(sockfd,5);  //listen for connections
connect(sfd,&destaddr,sizeof(destaddr);  //send connection request elsewhere
while(1){
  newsock=accept(sockfd,NULL,NULL);
  if(fork()==0){
    close(sockfd);
    send/recv;
  }
close(newsock);
}
```

Plus, would it be wrong to have the `connect()` within the while loop or after the `fork()`? I'm a bit confused about the interpretation of the while loop as also the fork. My intention is to run the same program in multiple machines and connect with each other. With this implementation i get a *connection refused* error when i try to connect to another p2p host (running the same client/server combo). Where can i place the connect() to ensure the program both connects outside and accepts incoming connections?

Comment: You use the `connect` function when you need to connect.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your problem is. Apparently, you know how to use that function. Please clarify the question to make it answerable.

Comment: My problem is when i'm trying to run the program in multiple machines and get a connection refused error. Also, i don't understand why there needs to be both a while loop and a fork to accept connections. Doesn't just the fork() take care of that?

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing socket programming for "Sever system" you need to use the following system function-

1. `socket()`
2. `bind()`
3. `listen()`
4. `accept()`
5. `read()/write()`// receive/send
6. `close()`

For "Client system"-

1. `socket()`
2. `connect()` // connect system call for the clients to connect with the server. Don't use this in server side
3. `read()/write()`// receive/send
4. `close()` - this functions are enough.

The template for the server process is: create server_socket, bind, listen, loop(accept, fork, send/recv) and the client template is: create client_socket, connect and send/recv. Can i do this? --- Ya. with this you can do it!

But i think your code snippet for server(So don't use `connect()` in server). Try the following changes-

For every system call check whether it is success are not. Upon on success all this system functions returns 0, upon failure all this functions returns -1. So only you will get to know where you are making mistake.

For Server side-

```
int sockfd,newsocket;
socklen_t addrlen;
struct sockaddr_in saddr;
struct sockaddr_in destaddr;

sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
listen(sockfd,5);  //listen for connections
while(1){
    newsock=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&destaddr,&addrlen); 
    //Check this accept system call. you should not use NULL for 2nd and 3rd arguments
    if(fork()==0){
    close(sockfd);
    send/recv;
  }
  close(newsock);
}
```

In Client side-

```
int sfd;
struct sockaddr_in saddr;

sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
connect(sfd,(struct sockaddr *)&saddr,sizeof(saddr);
send/recv
close(sfd);
```

[NOTE]: If you are new to Socket programming first try for server with single client system. If you got output for that, then you can try for server with multiple client. But when you are doing program for server with single client, The template for the server process is: create `server_socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `accept`, send/recv and `close`. The client template is: create `client_socket`, `connect`, Send/recv and `close`.